# Converting a pointer to int into a pointer to an array of int

Tags: c, pointers

I'm reading a book about the C language and it says

> The assignment of an array name to a pointer to an array of ints, such as `a`, is implicitly converted into a pointer to the array’s first element, not a pointer to the whole array and it requires an explicit type conversion.

So the following code would give "Error: mismatched pointer types".

```
int(*arrPtr)[4] = NULL;
int a[4] = {7, 8, 9, 5};
arrPtr = a;
```

We should change it to

```
arrPtr = (int(*)[4])a;
```

My question is why it's required to do type casting when we can simply get the address of the whole array `a` using `&` operator.

```
arrPtr = &a;
```

Is there any advantage in doing the cast? aren't they both the same?

Comment: Please finish the proper quotiation, i.e. from which book and in which edition you read that. Also, for any book source, you can often find "errata", which are corrections to statements made there in error.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Are you saying the book statement is inaccurate?. Anyway, I didn't mention it because the quotation was altered by me for brevity. FWIIW, the book is **C in a Nutshell, 2nd Edition by Peter Prinz, Tony Crawford (Chapter 9 Page 153)**

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include that info there, not here in the comments! And yes, it could be that the book makes misleading or downright wrong statements. Still, there's context missing: For example, it refers to "such as `a`", which is not defined in the quote you make.

Answer (score 1):

An explicit cast is needed here:

```
arrPtr = (int(*)[4])a;
```

Because the pointer types are not compatible.  However, that doesn't mean that such a conversion is valid.  Taking the address as you stated:

```
arrPtr = &a;
```

Would be the correct thing to do, and elements of `a` can then be access via `arrPtr` with notation such as `(*arrPtr)[n]`.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, here **a** is a pointer of type **int*** and points to the **0th** element of the array.
**arrPtr** is a pointer that can point to an array of 4 integers.
So **arrPtr** and **a** are two different pointer types. And the compiler throws a warning if you try to assign **a** to **arrPtr**. But you can still do this assignment in **C** however it is not the way to do it.
Note that **arrPtr = a** & **arrPtr = &a** assigns the same memory address to **arrPtr**. But for **&a** the compiler doesn't show any warning.

See the below progarm output to get more clarity on this,

```
int main()
{
    int(*arrPtr)[4] = NULL;
    int(*arrPtrtemp)[4] = NULL;
    int *ptr;
    int a[4] = {7, 8, 9, 5}; 
    arrPtr = a;
    arrPtrtemp = &a; 
    ptr = a;
    printf("arrPtr:%p\n", arrPtr);
    printf("arrPtrtemp:%p\n", arrPtrtemp);
    printf("ptr:%p\n", ptr);
    arrPtr++;
    arrPtrtemp++;
    ptr++;
    printf("arrPtr:%p\n", arrPtr);
    printf("arrPtrtemp:%p\n", arrPtrtemp);
    printf("ptr:%p\n", ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Will give the following output:

```
arrPtr:0x7ffc1bf19820
arrPtrtemp:0x7ffc1bf19820
ptr:0x7ffc1bf19820
arrPtr:0x7ffc1bf19830
arrPtrtemp:0x7ffc1bf19830
ptr:0x7ffc1bf19824
```

Note that **arrPtr** & **arrPtrtemp** are same and works same irrespective of the compiler warning. The purpose of this typecasting **arrPtr = (int(*)[4])a;** is to convet **int*** to **int(*)[4]**.
The main difference between **int* & int(*)[4]** comes in pointer arithmetic.
so if we assume the size of an integer is 4 bytes in our system, an operation like **ptr++**(an int* pointer) will increment the address by 4 bytes. And **arrPtr++** (an int(*)[4] pointer) will increment the address by 16 bytes.

**Edit:-**
here **a** is a pointer of type **int*** and points to the 0th element of the array. Change to the following,

When using the array name **a** to assign the address of the 0th element of the array, the compiler checks the pointer type of **a** as **int***. And by using **&** operator to get the address of array **a**, the compiler will treat the pointer type of **&a** as **int (*)[4]** in this case. And no warning will be displayed.

Comment: *here `a` is a pointer of type `int*`*... **Not true!** `a` is an **array** of 4 `int`.

Comment: @chqrlie Azerty to Qwerty, known problem :)